# Create a bar chart showing which month of every year for a city has the highest average sales using a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

The question from the paper: "By means of a bar chart - show the busiest months on average each year by
volume of sales in the City of Edinburgh, the bar chart should have 12 bars,
one for each month and the total should be an average of sales for that
month over every year of data available."

Therefore, here is a small representation of the DataFrame. NOTE: The original DataFrame is extremely large with many columns and rows so, this is just a shrunk version of the original.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/07/2020','01/08/2020','01/09/2020','01/10/2020','01/11/2020','01/12/2020','01/01/2021','01/01/2004','01/02/2004','01/03/2004','01/04/2004','01/05/2004','01/06/2004','01/07/2004','01/08/2004','01/09/2004','01/10/2004','01/11/2004','01/12/2004','01/01/2005','01/02/2005','01/03/2005'], 
                   'RegionName': ['City of Dundee', 'City of Dundee', 'City of Dundee', 'City of Dundee', 'City of Dundee', 'City of Dundee', 'City of Dundee','City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh', 'City of Edinburgh'],
                    'SalesVolume': ['156','191','321','324','313','','','1097','811','1092','1402','1345','1526','1573','1338','1286','1317','1247','1199','940','773','897']})

print(df)
```

Here is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/uk_hpi_dataset_2021_01.csv')

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

sales_vol = df[df['RegionName'].str.contains('City of Edinburgh')]

sales_vol.plot(x='Date', y='SalesVolume', kind = 'bar')
plt.show()
```

However, when I try to run this, I get a lot more than twelve bars and the dates are also not shown on the graph. Can anyone give me a hand in completing this question properly?

[Here is an image of the output I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk6Dr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, you want to generate a monthly SalesVolume average for your whole dataset for the City of Edinburgh. If so, the idea would be to create a month column and use groupby to calculate the monthly average. Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv ('C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/uk_hpi_dataset_2021_01.csv')

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda x:
                                               '{month}'.format(month=x.day).zfill(2))
sales_vol = df[df['RegionName'].str.contains('City of Edinburgh')]

sales_vol.groupby('Month').mean().plot(y='SalesVolume', kind = 'bar')
plt.show()
```

In this example I had to use "day" in the datetime format to extract the month, as your data is in the format YYYY-dd-mm.

Comment: I've tested your code and it seems to be the answer to my question so, thanks for your effort!